# PostgreSql запрос с подзапросом.

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Написал вот такой запрос

```
select number_nar, full_name, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, vrach_ortoped, vrach_technic, sum
from 
(j_nar left join j_patient on j_nar.id_patient = j_patient.id) WHERE date_close_nar is not null
```

Который выводит 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно посчитать количество рабочих дней между date_open_nar и date_close_nar и вывести их после sum .
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста составить sql запрос.

Comment: Праздники считаются выходными или рабочими? Или только субботы/воскресенья? Если что без производственного календаря точно не обойтись. В лучшем случае понадобится хранимая процедура, которая будет получать две даты на входе, пробегаться по календарю и выдавать искомое количество.

Comment: только выходные нужно не считать.(суббота/воскресенья)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

age(timestamp, timestamp)  interval  Subtract arguments, producing a "symbolic" result that uses years and months, rather than just days  age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13')  43 years 9 mons 27 days

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html

```
 select number_nar, full_name, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, vrach_ortoped, vrach_technic, sum, age(date_close_nar, date_open_nar)
    from 
    (j_nar left join j_patient on j_nar.id_patient = j_patient.id) WHERE date_close_nar is not null order by number_nar
```

Нет, так получается только по календарным дням, нужно по рабочим.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
select 
  number_nar, full_name, date_open_nar, date_close_nar, vrach_ortoped, vrach_technic, sum 
from j_nar 
left join j_patient on j_nar.id_patient = j_patient.id 
WHERE date_close_nar is not null
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]